# javascript for (i = 0; i < XXX.length; i++) -> length question

Tags: javascript, controls, loops

```
for (m = 0; m < troopsCount.length; m++) {

                //FM_log(7,"i="+i+" m="+m);
                //FM_log(7,"tipoTropaPrioritaria[m] = "+tipoTropaPrioritaria[m]);
                //FM_log(7,"troopsCount[m] = "+troopsCount[m]);
                //FM_log(7,"availableTroops[m] = "+availableTroops[m]);

                if ((tipoTropaPrioritaria[m] == null || tipoTropaPrioritaria[m] == "undefined")
|| (troopsCount[m] == null || troopsCount[m] == "undefined") ||
(availableTroops[m] == null || availableTroops[m] == "undefined")) 
                    return "alternaTropas(): ERRO - tipoTropaPrioritaria[m] || troopsCount[m] || availableTroops[m] null ou undefined";

                if ((parseInt(tipoTropaPrioritaria[m]) != 0) && (parseInt(troopsCount[m]) != 0)) {
                    naoServe = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    if ((parseInt(availableTroops[m])) < (parseInt(troopsCount[m]))) {
                        naoServe = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (m < troopsCount.length) {
                        naoServe = true;
                    }
                    else { //means m >= troopsCount.length
                        naoServe = false;
                    }
                }
}
```

my question is: the last statement

```
else { //means m >= troopsCount.length
    naoServe = false;
}
```

will it ever be evaluated since

for (m = 0; m < troopsCount.length; m++)

???

Comment: Are you sure `"undefined"`? Not `undefined`?

Comment: You really should declare "m" with "var": `for (var m = 0; ... )`

Comment: I see you try to check for `null` and `undefined`, actually you are already doing it just by comparing against `null` with the equals operator (`foo == null;` is enough), because `null == null` and `null == undefined;`...

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't be executed, assuming that `m` and `troopsCount` aren't modified in the loop itself (which in this example they don't seem to be).

As I believe you're pointing out, the loop's conditional would prevent the loop from running again if `m` were greater than or equal to `troopsCount.length` at the start of the loop.

Comment: ...or that `troopsCount` isn't modified either.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. It should never happen.

The loop stops immediately once `m < troopsCount.length` is false. As such, `m >= troopsCount.length` will never be true inside the loop, unless you change its value inside the loop itself (which you don't, in this sample).

Answer (score 0):

No. The loop is only evaluated as long as `m < troopsCount.length`. So `m` will never be `>= troopsCount.length` as long as you don't modify `m` or `troopsCount.length` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

let´s assume `troopsCount.length = 10`

when m = 9 it will execute all the code in the loop right, but when m = 10 it won´t execute anything.

so if I change it this way:

```
            else {
                if ((parseInt(availableTroops[m])) < (parseInt(troopsCount[m]))) {
                    naoServe = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if (m < (troopsCount.length - 1)) { // troopsCount.length - 1 = 9, m < 9 = m from 0 to 8
                    naoServe = true;
                }
                else { // troopsCount.length = 9
                    naoServe = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

it would work, right?

Comment: You should probably edit (or add comment to) your original question instead of posting this question as an answer.

Comment: since i´m assuming another condition (troopsCount.length = 10), I find it more stylish to post an answer to my question, since it is indeed an answer to my question, just waiting for someone with more knowledge than me confirm if my tought is right.